# BeagleBone Black says that incoming frame from Laptop Ethernet port is using Internet Protocol Version 6

Tags: ethernet, beagleboneblack

I am using a BeagleBone Black and try to connect it to the internet. The problem is that I am using Xenomai/RTnet on my BBB. Now when I connect my Ethernet port of BBB to Ethernet port of my Laptop my BBB says that it is getting frames with the Internet Protocol Version 6 and cannot handle that.
Output Putty:
`no one cared for packet with layer 3 protocol type 0x86dd`

I do not understand why my laptop send frames with IPv6. Does anyone has an answer for me?